# How to write Soap request with Zero or more repetitions in php

Tags: php, xml, soap, request

I want to write a soap request with Zero or more repetitions in php. I tried several times and couldn't complete. The issue is Zero or more repetitions. Please be kind to help for this.
Thanks

Example:-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ns3:GetAddresses xmlns:ns3="http://intechsolutions.com.au/soap2/">
    <ns3:Database>VPF</ns3:Database>
    <ns3:InputFields>NSW|2022|BONDI JUNCTION</ns3:InputFields>
    <ns3:StartFrom>0</ns3:StartFrom>
    <ns3:Properties>
    <ns3:item>
    <ns3:Name>UserID</ns3:Name>
    <ns3:Value>Mark</ns3:Value>
    </ns3:item>
    <ns3:item>
    <ns3:Name>Password</ns3:Name>
    <ns3:Value>p!jSc$&j8N5</ns3:Value>
    </ns3:item>
    <ns3:item>
    <ns3:Name>ReturnFormattedAddress</ns3:Name>
    <ns3:Value>True</ns3:Value>
    </ns3:item>
    </ns3:Properties>
    </ns3:GetAddresses>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Zero or more repetitions of what? Zero or more means any positive numer including Zero, right?

Comment: repetition of following things like.. <ns3:item>
    <ns3:Name>UserID</ns3:Name>
    <ns3:Value>Mark</ns3:Value>
    </ns3:item>
    <ns3:item>
    <ns3:Name>Password</ns3:Name>
    <ns3:Value>p!jSc$&j8N5</ns3:Value>
    </ns3:item>
    <ns3:item>
    <ns3:Name>ReturnFormattedAddress</ns3:Name>
    <ns3:Value>True</ns3:Value>
    </ns3:item>